# Crystal Reports Causes Application to Hang in crpe32.dll When Viewing Report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

All,

We have a C# Winform Application that uses Crystal Reports 13.0.9.  In production, our application is intermittently hanging.  The crash dump analysis appears to indicate that something withing Crystal Reports is causing blocked threads (i.e. deadlock).  The results of crash dump analysis from two different workstations and diagnostic information about one of the affected machines is included below.

When the error occurs, the users are simply trying to view the report.  The database is SQL Server 2012 Express but, the report does not pull data from the database.  Rather, data is pushed to the report via DataSet.  The Crystal Runtime is physically installed on the machine (i.e. they are not using a report server).  Unfortunately, our QA and development teams are unable to reproduce this issue in their respective environments.  We have hundreds of users using this application and version of Crystal and this seems to be the only isolated case where the application hangs on the Crystal DLLs.

I am fairly new to .NET and not quite sure how to interpret and/or further analyze the information in the dump analysis for troubleshooting purposes.  Can anyone please help us out?  Also, I apologize for putting the dump analysis and diagnostic information in a code block but, it was the only way I could post the information without errors.

### **Debug Diagnostic Tool (Dump Analysis)**

```
Detected a serious critical section related problem in PureService_MINI.dmp

Lock at crpe32+76f158 is Uninitialized

Impact analysis

10.00% of threads blocked
(Threads 9)

The following functions are involved in the root cause
crpe32+13e84

The following modules are involved in the root cause
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\crpe32.dll

The following vendors were identified for follow up based on root cause analysis

Unknown vendor for module C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\crpe32.dll

Please follow up with the vendors identified above

    Report for PureService_MINI.dmp
    Type of Analysis Performed   Hang Analysis 
    Machine Name   ADMIN-LSM 
    Operating System   Unexpected  
    Number Of Processors   4 
    Process ID   3880 
    Process Image   C:\Scribble\MarinaOffice.NET\PureService.exe 
    System Up-Time   00:00:00 
    Process Up-Time   01:03:31 



Top 5 Threads by CPU time
Note - Times include both user mode and kernel mode for each thread Thread ID: 0     Total CPU Time: 

    00:00:31.296     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 2     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.077     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 7     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.015     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 5     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.015     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 4     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.015     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 

NET Analysis Report
      CLR Information

.NET Threads Summary
CLR Information
CLR version = 4.0.30319.34014

CLR Debugger Extension = C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\x86Support\Exts\psscor4.dll

    .NET Threads Summary
    Failed to request ThreadStore
    Locked critical section report
    Critical Section    crpe32+76f158  
    Lock State   Uninitialized 
    Lock Count   1 
    Recursion Count   1 
    Entry Count   0 
    Contention Count   0 
    Spin Count   33556432 
    Owner Thread System ID   7988 (not present in dump) 

Thread report

    Thread 0 - System ID 7988
    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:00 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:24.687 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:06.609 

This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.

.NET Call Stack

Function 

    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef) 
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef) 
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef) 


Full Call Stack

Function   Source 
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c    
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+99    
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+12    
dtsagent+3376d    
sacommlayer+965c    
clientdoc+31995    
clientdoc+10961    
clientdoc+10b14    
clientdoc+27b07    
clr!JIT_MonExitWorker+a    
0x03eb1310    
0x09146f40    
0x114496b4    
0x114bf320    




Back to Top 


Thread 1 - System ID 4672
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:00 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 


Function   Source 
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+dc    
clr!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+98    
clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+cb    
clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+b9    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 2 - System ID 7832
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:00 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.062 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 




.NET Call Stack



Function 


Full Call Stack



Function   Source 
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+dc    
clr!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent+be    
clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+6e    
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+67    
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+82    
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+5b    
clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+198    
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4d    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 3 - System ID 4668
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:01 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




.NET Call Stack



Function 


Full Call Stack



Function   Source 
ntdll!NtDelayExecution+c    
KERNELBASE!SleepEx+8a    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadFire+3e    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart+6b    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 4 - System ID 4020
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:01 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




Function   Source 
ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+c    
KERNELBASE!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+44    
System_Data!SNIAsyncWait+71    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 5 - System ID 7308
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:01 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 




Function   Source 
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+dc    
user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+159    
user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+1f    
GdiPlus!BackgroundThreadProc+4b    
GdiPlus!DllRefCountSafeThreadThunk+10    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 6 - System ID 1988
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.



Function   Source 
user32!NtUserGetMessage+c    
user32!GetMessageW+2a    
mfc80u!AfxInternalPumpMessage+18   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 153 + f 
mfc80u!CWinThread::Run+54   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 625 + 7 
mfc80u!_AfxThreadEntry+10c   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 126 
msvcr80+29bb    
msvcr80+2a47    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 7 - System ID 7596
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.



Function   Source 
user32!NtUserGetMessage+c    
user32!GetMessageW+2a    
mfc80u!AfxInternalPumpMessage+18   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 153 + f 
mfc80u!CWinThread::Run+54   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 625 + 7 
mfc80u!_AfxThreadEntry+10c   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 126 
msvcr80+29bb    
msvcr80+2a47    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 8 - System ID 2880
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.



Function   Source 
user32!NtUserGetMessage+c    
user32!GetMessageW+2a    
mfc80u!AfxInternalPumpMessage+18   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 153 + f 
mfc80u!CWinThread::Run+54   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 625 + 7 
mfc80u!_AfxThreadEntry+10c   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 126 
msvcr80+29bb    
msvcr80+2a47    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 9 - System ID 8072
Entry point   0x00000000 
Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.



Function   Source 
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c    
ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+d0    
ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+a0    
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+42    
crpe32+13e84    
crpe32+13ec5 


Crash Dump Analysis (Workstation 2)
-----------------------------------
WARNING - DebugDiag was unable to locate debug symbols for crpe32.dll, so the information below may be incomplete.

Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at crpe32!MWCleanupProcess+3b3998 owned by thread 0 in PureService.dmp

Impact of this lock

9.09% of threads blocked

(Threads 9)

The following functions are trying to enter this critical section

crpe32!Ordinal995+13e84

The following module(s) are involved with this critical section

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\crpe32.dll from SAP BusinessObjects

The following vendors were identified for follow up based on root cause analysis

SAP BusinessObjects

Please follow up with the vendors identified above

Report for PureService.dmp

    Type of Analysis Performed   Hang Analysis 
    Machine Name   ADMIN-LSM 
    Operating System   Unexpected  
    Number Of Processors   4 
    Process ID   3880 
    Process Image   C:\Scribble\MarinaOffice.NET\PureService.exe 
    System Up-Time   1 day(s) 04:57:28 
    Process Up-Time   01:03:06





Top 5 Threads by CPU time

    Note - Times include both user mode and kernel mode for each thread Thread ID: 0     Total CPU Time: 00:00:31.296     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 2     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.077     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 7     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.015     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 5     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.015     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000 
    Thread ID: 4     Total CPU Time: 00:00:00.015     Entry Point for Thread: 0x00000000







.NET Analysis Report
CLR Information

.NET Threads Summary
CLR Information
CLR version = 4.0.30319.34014



CLR Debugger Extension = C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\x86Support\Exts\psscor4.dll




.NET Threads Summary

    Failed to request ThreadStore
    Locked critical section report
    Critical Section    crpe32!MWCleanupProcess+3b3998  
    Lock State   Locked 
    Lock Count   1 
    Recursion Count   1 
    Entry Count   0 
    Contention Count   1 
    Spin Count   33556432 
    Owner Thread   0 
    Owner Thread System ID   7988 




Thread report

Thread 0 - System ID 7988

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:00 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:24.687 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:06.609 



This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.



.NET Call Stack



Function 

    CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(System.Object ByRef, Int32) 
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.CRPE.PEOpenEngineEx(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PEEngineOptions ByRef) 
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef) 
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef) 
    System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef) 

Full Call Stack



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c    
    KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+99    
    KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+12    
    dtsagent+3376d    
    sacommlayer!DllGetClassObject+16dc    
    clientdoc!DllGetClassObject+2b26b    
    clientdoc!DllGetClassObject+a237    
    clientdoc!DllGetClassObject+a3ea    
    clientdoc!DllGetClassObject+213dd    
    clr!JIT_MonExitWorker+a    
    0x03eb1310    
    0x09146f40    
    0x114496b4    
    0x114bf320    



Back to Top 


Thread 1 - System ID 4672

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:00 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
    KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+dc    
    clr!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+98    
    clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+cb    
    clr!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+b9    
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    



Back to Top 


Thread 2 - System ID 7832

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:00 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.062 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 



.NET Call Stack



Function 


Full Call Stack



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
    KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+dc    
    clr!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent+be    
    clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+6e    
    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+67    
    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+82    
    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+5b    
    clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+198    
    clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4d    
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    



Back to Top 


Thread 3 - System ID 4668

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:01 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 



.NET Call Stack



Function 


Full Call Stack



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtDelayExecution+c    
    KERNELBASE!SleepEx+8a    
    clr!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadFire+3e    
    clr!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart+6b    
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    



Back to Top 


Thread 4 - System ID 4020

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:01 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+c    
    KERNELBASE!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+44    
    System_Data!SNIAsyncWait+71    
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    



Back to Top 


Thread 5 - System ID 7308

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 2:33:01 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
    KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+dc    
    user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+159    
    user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+1f    
    GdiPlus!BackgroundThreadProc+4b    
    GdiPlus!DllRefCountSafeThreadThunk+10    
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    



Back to Top 


Thread 6 - System ID 1988

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 



Function   Source 

    user32!NtUserGetMessage+c    
    user32!GetMessageW+2a    
    mfc80u!AfxInternalPumpMessage+18   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 153 + f 
    mfc80u!CWinThread::Run+54   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 625 + 7 
    mfc80u!_AfxThreadEntry+10c   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 126 
    msvcr80!_callthreadstartex+1b   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 348 + 6 
    msvcr80!_threadstartex+66   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 326 + 5 
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    



Back to Top 


Thread 7 - System ID 7596

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.015 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 



Function   Source 

    user32!NtUserGetMessage+c    
    user32!GetMessageW+2a    
    mfc80u!AfxInternalPumpMessage+18   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 153 + f 
    mfc80u!CWinThread::Run+54   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 625 + 7 
    mfc80u!_AfxThreadEntry+10c   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 126 
    msvcr80!_callthreadstartex+1b   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 348 + 6 
    msvcr80!_threadstartex+66   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 326 + 5 
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 8 - System ID 2880

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




Function   Source 

    user32!NtUserGetMessage+c    
    user32!GetMessageW+2a    
    mfc80u!AfxInternalPumpMessage+18   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 153 + f 
    mfc80u!CWinThread::Run+54   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 625 + 7 
    mfc80u!_AfxThreadEntry+10c   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp @ 126 
    msvcr80!_callthreadstartex+1b   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 348 + 6 
    msvcr80!_threadstartex+66   f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 326 + 5 
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b    




Back to Top 


Thread 9 - System ID 8072

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 3:28:20 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c    
    ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+d0    
    ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+a0    
    ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+42    
    crpe32!Ordinal995+13e84    
    crpe32!Ordinal995+13ec5    



Back to Top 


Thread 10 - System ID 4756

    Entry point   0x00000000 
    Create time   10/8/2014 3:36:03 PM 
    Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 
    Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00 




.NET Call Stack



Function 


Full Call Stack



Function   Source 

    ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c    
    KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+99    
    clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+bf    
    clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait+12f    
    clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+309    
    clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4d    
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e    
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+20    
    ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b 


System Diagnostic Information
-----------------------------

    [System Summary]
    Item Value
    OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Professional x64 
    OS Version 6.1 Service Pack 1 (Build 7601)
    System Name RENTAL
    System Model OptiPlex 760                 
    System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
    Processor Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz
    BIOS Version DELL   - 15
    IP 192.168.234.4
    Windows Directory C:\Windows
    System Directory C:\Windows\system32
    Locale United States
    User Name Rentals
    Time Zone Central Standard Time
    Total Physical Memory 3933 MB
    Available Physical Memory 1100 MB
    Serial number H2RN5J1
    MAC address 00-23-AE-8D-BD-AD
```